# SQl Query to break results into specifically sized groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query to identify 5 groups of different size. I know I can use NTILE to break my set up into equal size groups but I need something like this

```
Total Records say 1,000,000

Group 1 100,000 Rows
Group 2 200,000 Rows
Group 3 300,000 Rows
Group 4 400,000 Rows
```

Thanks

Comment: Do the groups relate to each other in some way or are these just arbitrary amounts to split it into?

Comment: Nope I just need to split them in specific non equal proportions

Comment: Do you want to be able to do more or less groups and change the varying sizes?

Comment: Assuming you say *SQL* (as in Structured Query Language), but you **really** mean (Microsoft) **SQL Server** - correct?

Comment: So why not use NTILE again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, use `row_number()` and logic on top of that:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 100000 then 'Group1'
             when seqnum <= 100000 + 200000 then 'Group2'
             when seqnum <= 100000 + 200000 + 300000 then 'Group3'
             when seqnum <= 100000 + 200000  + 300000 + 400000 then 'Group4'
         end) as GroupName,
       t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by <your criteria>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```